# How can I group two elastich column and how can I sum this groups on elastich search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have some elastich datas like this:

**log**

```
{
"bet" : 5,
"win" : 10
}
```

**another log**

```
{
"bet" : 5,
"win" : 15
}
```

**another log**

```
{
"bet" : 5,
"win" : 10
}
```

and I want to *sum* like this info:

e.g. : `win / bet => 2` , how many I have this log, I want sum,
this should be response

`2` (this is rate) => `3` (this is log count)

`3` (this is rate) => `1` (this is log count)

*Not : I use php, for elastich queries.*

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with a [sum aggregation and a little bit of scripting on a runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html#_script_14).

Comment: Thanks your response, This is collecting all rate, I want to see how many I have each rate